# cant retrive data from random list data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrive data from firebase database ,the structure will follow this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GGxz.png)

I am using the following code

```
 private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private ListView poemListView;

    private ArrayList<String> poemList =new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        String[] items = new String[]{"Father","Mom","Love", "FreindShip", "Nature","Happy","Inspiration","Sad"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);

        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

        String dropDownString=dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();

  mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(dropDownString);


 poemListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.poemList);

 arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,poemList);

        poemListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                poemList1.add(value);

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

When i debug the code ,the code is running fine till

```
{ String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); }
```

for ex:  only one record is fetched (checked in debug mode) under father catogery  .

help me to retrive all the data's in the list